# Filter Column on Analytic:reportchart not a valid filterable column

Tags: visualforce, reporting, dynamic-visualforce, analytics

I have created a vf page with a standard controller equal to the Account Object. In the report that I am trying to bring in on the vf page it has the Invoice_History__c object and the Account object on the report. I used this code line to bring in the report

```
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OK0000000PLDV" 
                       filter="{column:'Id', operator: 'equals', value: '{!Id}'}" size="small">
</analytics:reportChart>
```

but everytime it states "For the filter 1: Specify a valid filterable column because Id is invalid"

I have tried using `Account.Id, AccountId, Id, Invoice_History__c.Account__c.Id` and nothing works.

Ideally when the user clicks on the button to reference the vf page I have created i want the report to filter on that specific account id that the button is on.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I've figured out that I just had to add `ACCOUNT_ID` as it is case sensitive:

```
filter="{column:'ACCOUNT_ID', operator: 'equals', value: '{!Id}'}"
```

That worked out!

Answer (score 1):

For those who might face this issue. I have a similar issue, but my requirment was to filter on custom object and its relationship. like Inventory__c.case__r.recordtype. Inventory custom object have case lookup and want to filter on its record type. So when i write like this:

```
{column:'Inventory__c.case__r.recordtype', operator:'notEqual', value:''}
```

it says:

> Specify a valid filterable column

Its solution is this:

```
{column:'FK_CASE_RECORDTYPE', operator:'notEqual', value:''}
```

I was using inventory__c as standard controller on page and i get this solution from this post.

[Embed report chart to visualforce filter issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139890/embed-report-chart-to-visualforce-filter-issue)

What actually happen is Salesforce has its own api names when you use them in filter which you can get by querying reports metadata.