# Issue in Filtering Analytic ReportChart in VF page

Tags: visualforce, filters, analytics-reportchart

I am trying to filter my report chart embedded in a VFpage based on AccountID. My VF code is as below

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" sidebar="False" showHeader="False"  >
 <analytics:reportChart reportID="00Op0000000H5E2"
  cacheAge="86400000" 
  showRefreshButton="False" 
 size="small"
  filter="[{column:'Account_ID',operator:'equals',value:'{!Account.ID}'}]"></analytics:reportChart>
```

I used Analytics Apex Library to get API Name of AccountID column as below

```
Reports.ReportDescribeResult describe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport('00Op0000000H5E2');
```

However I keep getting data without being filtered.i.e, for all accounts
I am embedding this VFpage in accounts layout. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After some search answer from here [Filter Column on Analytic:reportchart not a valid filterable column](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60882/filter-column-on-analyticreportchart-not-a-valid-filterable-column)

The ACCOUNT_ID is case sensitive